# Would you send this simple SQL back for rework?

Tags: sql, oracle

We have a web application in which the users perform ad-hoc queries based on parameters that have been entered. I might also mention that response time is of high importance to the users.

The web page dynamically construct a SQL to execute based on the parameters entered. For example, if the user enters "1" for "Business Unit" we construct a SQL like this:

```
SELECT * FROM FACT WHERE 
BUSINESS_UNIT = '1'
--AND other criteria based on the input params
```

I found that where the user does not specify a BUSINESS_UNIT the following query is constructed

```
SELECT * FROM FACT WHERE 
BUSINESS_UNIT LIKE '%'
--AND other criteria based on the input params
```

IMHO, this is unnecessarily (if not grossly) inefficient and warrants sending the code bad for modification but since I have a much higher rate of sending code back for rework than others, I believe that I may be earning a reputation as being "too picky."

If this is an inappropriate question because it is not a direct coding Q, let me know and I will delete it immediately. I am very confused whether subjective questions like this are allowed or not! I'll be watching your replies.

ty

---

Update:

I am using an Oracle database.

My impression is that Oracle does not optimize "LIKE '%'" by removing the condition and that leaving it in is less efficient. Could someone confirm?

Comment: You know who else was too picky?  MICHELANGELO.

Comment: As you can see from Womp's answer, in this situation you do not need to send the code back, because most SQL query optimizers will handle this example efficiently. However, I am curious as to whether or not the developer *knew* that it would be optimized in such a way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although that looks grossly inefficient, I just tested it out in SQL Server, and the query optimizer was smart enough to filter it out.

In other words,

```
SELECT * FROM FACT WHERE 
BUSINESS_UNIT LIKE '%'
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM FACT
```

generated the exact same query plan.  So there shouldn't be a performance difference (depending on your DB engine I guess), although it does look kind of sloppy.

That may affect your decision to send it back or not.  Personally I probably would, but if you're under a cloud already then it's something you can probably relax on, at least in terms of performance.

Comment: Beat me to it, just finished testing this on my machine and I came to the same conclusion.

Answer (score 14):

The two queries are completely different (from the point of view of a result set)

```
SELECT * FROM FACT;
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM FACT WHERE  
BUSINESS_UNIT LIKE '%';
```

The first will return all rows, the second, if there are `NULL` values those rows will not be returned because anything compared to `NULL` is `NULL` and therefore does not satisfy the predicate. This is how it would work in Oracle.

Comment: First person to note the "NULL" gotcha. I believe some RDBMS handle this differently, this is probably why MS SQL Server can optimize this away, while Oracle obviously cannot (unless the column is non-NULL)

Answer (score 2):

That query, with the `BUSINESS_UNIT LIKE '%'`, doesn't look quite efficient -- I suppose it'll force a full scan of the table...

So, yes, I would try to have that query reworked, to deal with that kind of situation in a proper way -- or, at least, **I would report that problem through our bug-tracker** *(Not sure of the priority I would assign, but, still, the problem would be logged somewhere, and someone will correct it someday, when there is no higher-priority problem to deal with)*.

Answer (score 2):

SELECT * is a red flag.  Specify a column list for the query.

Answer (score 1):

I would send it back and I like the question.

All code review is to some extent subjective.  The criteria should be based on a number of factors.

- Does it work.
- Does it meet reasonable expectations of performance, maintainability, usability, and scalability

While I have not tested this particular construct -- I suspect (as do you) this code will do horrible things to your SQL server.  Thus performance and scalability are called into question.

Answer (score 1):

The writer wanted a dummy statement so that he/she could append "and" to all the subsequent statements. changing it to a better "no-op" statement like 1==1 would help. Or they could do slightly more work and insert the "where" intelligently.

Answer (score 1):

I would question why **bind variables** are not being used (unless there is a good reason in particular cases):

```
SELECT * FROM FACT WHERE 
BUSINESS_UNIT = '1'
```

Why is it not:

```
SELECT * FROM FACT WHERE 
BUSINESS_UNIT = :bu
```